# Using :owner in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry for simple and maybe for you stupid quation.

In model have next line code:

```
belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
```

I cant found in project model Owner. What is this owner in Rails and how use it? Where can i found more information about this?

Comment: Read about polymorphic associations in Rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This association is polymorphic. This means that in the database you actually have two columns: `owner_id` and `owner_type`, and in the `owner_type` column you have the class name of the associated model.

You can read more about it here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations